# How to keep the state variable value intact upon screen reload

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React and I tried to toggle the Login/Logout based on the current state of authentication. I've used Google OAuth to perform the authentication.

I have a state variable to say if the user is authenticated or not and is defaulted to false. Upon successful authentication, I set the state to true.

Now the problem is, after completing a successful authentication, when I refresh the screen, the screen reloads and I see the console.log printing false and login appears momentarily. And after a second the console.log prints true and then the logout appears. How do I avoid showing login screen (for that one second after refreshing the screen) when the authentication is completed? Can someone help me please? Thanks.

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
}, [])

const handleSuccessAuth = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true)
}

const handleFailureAuth = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
}

const handleLogout = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
}

console.log(isAuthenticated)
if(!isAuthenticated)
{
    return (
            <div>
                <LoginView
                    handleSuccessAuth = {handleSuccessAuth}
                    handleFailureAuth = {handleFailureAuth}
                />
            </div>
           )
}
else
{            
    return (
            <div>    
                <LogoutView
                    handleLogout = {handleLogout}
                />
            </div>)
}
```

Comment: maybe you should store whether the user is authenticated or not in the local storage, and use this value when calling `useState`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé You should never store user authentication details in local storage. That is a big security no no.

Comment: pfff, I didn't mean to store the authentication details, just a flag with `true` or `false` value whether the user is authenticated or not

Answer (score 0):

If your variable goes from false to true it means your code is doing something, probably an AJAX call, my recommendation is to show a loading scree/message until the AJAX request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep the variable intact on reload but you can keep a variable that tracks if the user authentication has been initialized and show a loading indicator in the meantime

```js
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
const [authLoaded, setAuthLoaded] = useState(false)

// this does nothing, passing false to useState above sets the initial value
// useEffect(() => {
//     setIsAuthenticated(false)
// }, [])

const handleSuccessAuth = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true)
    setAuthLoaded(true)
}

const handleFailureAuth = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
    setAuthLoaded(true)
}

const handleLogout = x => {
    setIsAuthenticated(false)
}

console.log(isAuthenticated)

if (!authLoaded) {
  return <div>loading...</div>
}

if(!isAuthenticated)
{
    return (
            <div>
                <LoginView
                    handleSuccessAuth = {handleSuccessAuth}
                    handleFailureAuth = {handleFailureAuth}
                />
            </div>
           )
}
else
{            
    return (
            <div>    
                <LogoutView
                    handleLogout = {handleLogout}
                />
            </div>)
}
```

Comment: Will this not return “loading…” every time? I don’t think Login screen will ever appear.

Comment: Once the authentication is handled either `handleSuccessAuth` or `handleFailureAuth` gets called I'm assuming and both will switch `authLoaded` to true and reveal either the login or logout page

Comment: I’m sorry, but I don’t get it. For the authentication to happen, we have to have authLoaded set to be true. But we always return “loading…” not letting the next statement to execute. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: @Gosu sorry I was missing a closing bracket. You're right, you should only show loading if `!authLoaded`

Comment: @Gosu I see what you're saying now. This is more of an organization problem. You should store the authLoaded variable in the LoginView and handle the loading screen in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe olivier-boisse alluded to using localStorage to persist your state. You can use an `useEffect` hook to persist your `isAuthenticated` to localStorage when the value updates, and use a [state initializer function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) to read in the initial state from local storage.

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(() => {
  return !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('auth');
});

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(isAuthenticated));
}, [isAuthenticated]);
```